# Django cannot authenticate or password hashing is wrong

Tags: python, django

I use a custom user model so I can authenticate using email instead of username.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin,
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(
        self,
        email,
        password,
        confirm_code=None,
        username=None,
        role=None,
    ):
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.confirm_code = confirm_code
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, role, username=None):
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.role = role
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    EM = "EM"
    SM = "SM"
    DH = "DH"
    ST = "ST"
    ROLES = [
        (EM, "Executive Management"),
        (SM, "Senior Management"),
        (DH, "Department Head"),
        (ST, "Staff Member"),
    ]

    objects = UserManager()
    role = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ROLES, default=US, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    confirm_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_profile = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_verified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"
        ordering = ["username"]
        db_table = "users"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"{self.slug}"

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["role"]
```

When I register a user the user is created in the database correctly and the password is hashed I assume correctly, because I see the hash and not the raw password. Here is the method I used to register a user with:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def RegisterUser(request, *args, **kwargs):
    code = []
    numbers = range(7)
    for num in numbers:
        code.append(randint(0, 9))

    email = request.data["email"]
    confirmemail = request.data["confirmemail"]
    password = request.data["password"]
    confirmpassword = request.data["confirmpassword"]
    errors = []
    if email != confirmemail:
        errors.append("emailmatch")
        return Response("Emails do not match", status=500)
    if confirmpassword != password:
        errors.append("passmatch")
        return Response("Password do not match", status=500)
    if User.objects.filter(email=email):
        errors.append("emailexists")
        return Response("User is already registered", status=500)
    else:
        pass
    if len(errors) > 0:
        return Response(False)
    else:
        password_to_save = make_password(password)
        confirm_code = "".join(str(e) for e in code)
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email=email, password=password_to_save, confirm_code=confirm_code
        )
        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
        from_email = "info@website.com"
        link = f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/confirm/{user.id}/{token}/"
        context = {"link": link, "code": code}
        template = get_template("emails/welcome.html").render(context)

        subject = "Successfully registered"
        message = "Welcome to website"

        try:
            send_mail(
                subject,
                message=message,
                from_email=from_email,
                recipient_list=[email],
                html_message=template,
            )
        except:
            return Response("Could not send mail")

        serializer = RegisterSerializer(user)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have a custom backend to authenticate a user using an email instead of a username and here that is:

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        email = kwargs.get("email", None)
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        if user:
            breakpoint()
            if user.check_password(kwargs.get("password", None)):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        else:
            User.DoesNotExist
        return None
```

It just doesn't work and I cannot log in. The user is active! If I do a breakpoint() as seen here and I check the password manually by entering the raw password in user.check_password('password') then it returns false. So isn't check_password supposed to then hash the raw password entered and compare that hash with the hash in the database or how does it work?

This works:

```
password = "hello"
saved = make_password(password)
true = check_password(password, saved)
```

So how why does it not work in my Authenticate backend which is exactly the same?

Do I need to use another hashing algorithm or what?

What am I supposed to do then and how can I authenticate a user? Is there another way to compare the password a user entered on a form and the hashed password saved in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `set_password` function in `create_user` in your manager. This method itself calls `make_password` function.

So, when you pass a hashed password generated via `make_password` to `create_user`, that hashed password would be hashed again in `set_password` function.

So there is no need to call `make_password` by yourself. Just pass plain password to `create_user` method.